# Health Check Failures and 502 Errors with HAProxy and Golang Fiber Instances

Tags: ubuntu, load-balancing, haproxy, go

I have a setup where Server A acts as the client, communicating with Server B through HAProxy. Server B runs four similar Golang Fiber instances, each with Prefork enabled on an EC2 t3xlarge instance. Server B handles thousands of requests per second. However, I've been noticing issues with health checks and 502 errors returned by HAProxy, likely indicating failed health checks.

**Frontend Configuration:**

```
frontend apifront
    bind *:9898
    maxconn 50000
    mode http
    log global
    default_backend apiserver
```

**Backend Configuration:**

```
backend apiserver
    mode http
    option http-keep-alive
    timeout connect 5s
    timeout server 30s
    timeout queue 60s
    timeout check 5s
    timeout http-request 10s
    timeout http-keep-alive 10s
    http-reuse safe
    log global
    option httpchk GET /health
    balance roundrobin
    server apiserver1 localhost:9881 check
    server apiserver2 localhost:9882 check
    server apiserver3 localhost:9883 check
    server apiserver4 localhost:9884 check
```

**Observations:**

1. All servers fail health checks more times than expected.
2. Frequent 502 errors are returned by HAProxy as seen in Server A's logs

**Questions:**

1. Is the observed behavior of frequent health check failures and 502 errors expected in this setup?
2. Are there ways to troubleshoot and identify the root cause of the health check failures?
3. What adjustments or fine-tuning can be made to improve the reliability of health checks and reduce 502 errors?
4. As a newcomer to server setup configurations, are there best practices or additional checks I should consider?

Any insights or guidance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. I am also ready to provide any more details about my setup that will help. Thank you!

Comment: Your health checks are failing on server B, look at what happening on that server.